# Adapting a TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-pic

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, angles,quotes,babel,3d}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
 \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{
innenboxstyle/.style={
sidebyside adapt=right, 
bicolor,colback=gray!10, colbacklower=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\scriptsize,
 sharpish corners, colframe=gray!20!black, colbacktitle=gray!40,coltitle=black,
scale=1.0, 
sidebyside align=top seam,
left=0mm, 
valign lower=center, 
halign lower=center, 
},
seitenboxstyle/.style={
sidebyside, 
sidebyside align=top seam, 
sidebyside gap=3mm,
sharpish corners,
lower separated=false,
colframe=gray!10!black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries
},
innenboxstylezwei/.style={
bicolor,colback=gray!10, colbacklower=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\scriptsize,
 sharpish corners, colframe=gray!20!black, colbacktitle=gray!40,coltitle=black,
scale=1.0,
sidebyside align=top seam,
left=0mm,
valign lower=center, 
halign lower=center,
},
}
% ====================================

\newcommand\titelbereich{Drawing}
\newcommand\textbereich{\subsubsection*{Area}
\begin{equation*}
A=g\cdot h
\end{equation*}
% here a dotted gray line
\subsubsection*{Circumference}
\begin{equation*}
u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b
\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\bildbereich{\begin{tikzpicture}[my angle/.style={font=\small, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm}]
  \node (a) [trapezium,trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120, minimum width=30mm, draw, very thick, label=below:\scriptsize g, label=left:\scriptsize ] {};
  \draw [densely dashed, very thick] (a.north west) coordinate (a nw) -- (a nw |- a.south) node [midway,right] {$\scriptstyle h$} ;
  \coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
  \coordinate (a brc) at (a.bottom right corner);
 
%here a dotted, gray line with another parallelogramm below the line
\end{tikzpicture}}

% =====================================

\begin{document}
%========================
\tcbsidebyside[innenboxstyle, title={\titelbereich},]{\textbereich}{\bildbereich}
%========================
\end{document}
```

I have to add the following things to the drawing above:

(1) I need a gray dotted line between the "Area" equation and the "Circumference" equation.

(2) Furthermore, I need the same line on the right hand side below the parallelogram. Under the line there should be another parallelogram. The edges of this parallelogram are a and b, respectively.

(3) Both dotted lines should be on the same height.

I have tried to use `\draw[dotted]` which did not work. Neither on the left hand side, nor on the right hand side.
Here is a sketch:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I think the first word in your question should be "Adapting".

Comment: PLease provide a sketch what you after. With it your question will become more clear ...

Comment: Is tcbsidebyside really the way to go?  You can use minipages instead.  You just need to know how wide to make them.

Comment: The tcbsidebyside is a solution suggested by another user. 
Actually, there are two columns with severals boxes within an outer box. I removed the other parts due to the MWE principle.

Comment: It would be really nice to have a solution without using tabularray, since I am not able to include the necessary package.

Comment: I suspect this is a tcolorbox issue, which was probably unclear since the task wasn't specified.
Here the sidebyside-box is to be combined with the "upper part" and "lower part" of a normal tcolorbox. And that doesn't work as far as I know. The only thing that comes to mind is, that you nest the two different boxes: two sidebyside-boxes in a normal box. Then you should be able to use `\tcblower` again and then you'll also have the dashed line.

Comment: BTW: If you do it this way, you will probably have to change various distances or set them to zero. There is also the option 'minimal', on the other hand, the distances are also described at the beginning of the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit (1):**

- It is not clear how large is your real table
- Can it be fit in one page?
- If yes, you can use `tblr` table:

**Edit:**

- as OP complain in comment that first wo column haven't gray fill, now this are added,
- some small improvements of table code is done too (commands for dashed lines are moved to table preamble)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                babel,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadings, shapes.geometric,
                3d}
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small, 
                       angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, very thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Trapezium/.style = {base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math, rightsep=24pt]
                        Q[c]},
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &  
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\   
        &   &   \\         
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

- As you can see, I define common styles for all images in table,
- Both `tikzpicture`s are drawn from scratch.

[image]

**Edit (2)**

- Improved table preamble and added images when table span two pages.
- In the case that it need to spread over several page, than the `longtblr` table come to account:
- Using it, you need to remove `center` environment and change table preamble to:

```
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape, fg=gray1}
\begin{longtblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
                 hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
                 colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                            Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math, rightsep=24pt]
                            Q[c]},
                 cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
                 row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
                 row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt},
                 rowhead = 1
                 }
```

- even rows are in table body are terminated by `\\*`
- In the case, when in table body are eight time repeated content of above example) with considered aforementioned change of rows terminations

```
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\*   % <----
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\*   % <----
        &   &   \\
```

table is:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to compile your code: tabularray.sty not found. 
Is there a way to solve it without tabularray?

Comment: @KevinC, the simple way is to load `tabularray` package. Just use your LaTeX installation  vizard, find package ant that is all ...

Comment: unfortunately, is seems not to be that easy. I can not find the tabularray package in my TeX Live Utility. There is only ```tabulary```.

Comment: And it also seems, that the gray background on the left hand side is missing.

Comment: Do you have recent TeXline? For gray column color, if you like to have, I would add ASAP (to my opinion is not beautiful, but all is up to you).

Comment: What do you mean by TeXline?

Comment: @KevinC, sory, TeXlive. Just typing error ...

Comment: @KevinC, I use MiKTeX, where upload ˛tabularray˛is simple, unfortunately I'm not familiar with TeXlive. Package `tabularray` you can also find on CTAN: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray?lang=en

Comment: I upgraded to TexLive 2023 and now the tabularray issue works. 
Now, I have a different error, which I posted here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682427/compiling-error-missing-item

Answer (score 0):

With `tcbitemize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
NoGaps/.style={boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt},
enhanced,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
NoGaps, sharp corners, 
before title=\vspace{1ex}\hspace{0.75ex}, after title=\vspace{1ex},% looks better
title={Main Title}, 
fonttitle=\bfseries,    coltitle=black,
colbacktitle=gray!40,
%colframe=black, 
boxrule=1.4pt,
]
\begin{tcbitemize}[
raster columns=100, % is equivalent to  100% 
raster equal height=rows,
sharp corners, boxrule=0pt, 
% NoGaps, % optional
enhanced,% needed for ...xxx...
raster row 1/.style={
borderline south={1.0pt}{0pt}{densely dashed}, % ...xxx... that
%bottomrule=3mm,  %  would enough  if 'dashed' is not  desired
},
raster column skip=0pt,
raster row skip=0pt,
raster before skip=0pt,
raster after skip=0pt,
colback=gray!20,
]
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=75] Upper Left (75\% of width)
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=25, colback=white] Upper Right (25\% of width)
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=75] Lower Left
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=25, colback=white] Lower Right \\ 1 \\ 2\\ 3 
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```